# Searching timestamp with query but ignoring the time

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

geniuses!

so in my project i'm trying to use a query to search my single-table-database by timestamp, which is formatted like this: "2018-05-01 00:28:43".
In my request i would like to ignore the time and display all the results which have the chosen date as a timestamp.

Now i'm still learning, tried a lot of searching but could not come up with an answer. This is where i'm at:

```
def index
  if params[:query].present?
    @reports = Report.where(created_at: params[:query])
  else
    @reports = Report.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: See the rails server log. what query is running. What is the column type of created_at

Comment: sqlite3 for training purposes

Comment: Report Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE "reports"."created_at" = ?  [["created_at", "2018-05-01 00:00:00"]]

Comment: column type is datetime

Comment: I think it would be useful if you could specify if you're looking for a SQL query or ActiveRecord query. Where would you like to display those results ?

Comment: I'm looking for an ActiveRecord query i guess, i would like to display those results on the index of the corresponding view.
The actual displaying of the results is not really the problem, the problem is actually getting the results im looking for.

Comment: so, params[:query] is a string timestamp? what format?

Comment: params[:query] is a date from a datepicker, formatted like this: "2018-05-01"

Comment: entering a query basically looks like this:
http://localhost:3000/reports?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=2018-05-01

Comment: if i add a time to the query manually it does work, i just want it to ignore the time and display all the results from the requested date.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
def index
  if params[:query].present?
    # gives a date without a time 
    date = Date.parse(params[:query])
    @reports = Report.where(created_at: date..(date + 1.day)) 
  else
    @reports = Report.all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
def index
  if params[:query].present?
    @reports = Report.where(created_at: (Time.new(params[:query]).beginning_of_day()..Time.new(params[:query]).end_of_day()).all
  else
    @reports = Report.all
  end
end
```

If you need to format the results you can parse the column using all.map( ) like this

```
Report.where(created_at: (Time.new(params[:query]).beginning_of_day()..Time.new(params[:query]).end_of_day()).all.map{|report| report.created_at = Time.new(report.created_at).your_format }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL [`date()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function.

```
def index
  @date = Date.parse(params[:query]) rescue nil
  if @date
    @reports = Report.where("date(created_at) = ?", @date)
  else
    @reports = Report.all
  end
end
```

Do not pass `params[:query]` directly as an argument for `where` clause, parse it to `Date` object first to make sure that it's actually a date.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def index
  if params[:query].present?
    date = Date.parse(params[:query])
    @reports = Report.where(created_at: date.midnight..date.end_of_day)
  else
    @reports = Report.all
  end
end
```